Immediate promise chain not executing as expected?


function foo(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => console.log(num));
}

foo(1).then(() => {
  foo(3);
});



The function foo returns an immediately resolve promise. "1" is printed, but why doesn't the chain continue with printing "3"?

The function foo returns an immediately resolve promise No it doesn't. You never call resolve. So the promise is forever in the pending state.

@NicholasTower Why doesn't it just resolve to undefined?

It's not going to automatically resolve itself, because that's not the purpose of new Promise. new Promise is used when you have some arbitrary asynchronous task which you want to wrap in a promise. Only you know when your arbitrary code is done, so it's up to you to tell the promise when you're finished. If you havn't called resolve yet, the promise assumes the work is still in progress, and so it remains in the pending state. If for some reason you never call resolve, then the promise remains in pending forever.

@NicholasTower makes sense. I was assuming that new promise knows the code has finished and will resolve automatically

@JobHunter69 The function foo indeed creates a promise but does not explicitly call resolve() to resolve the promise. Therefore, the promise returned by foo never completes or resolves.


function foo(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log(num);
    resolve(); 
  });
}

foo(1).then(() => {
  return foo(3);
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Chain continued successfully.");
});




You need to resolve Promise like this:


function foo(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log(num)
    resolve()
  });
}

foo(1).then(() => {
  foo(3);
});



